# JSONP Callback not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsonp

I am trying to get some JSONP to work but the callback function doesn't seem to get called. I have looked at other questions but my code looks like others that have worked - any ideas?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callbackFunc(jsonp){
            alert('In callback');
            alert(jsonp);
        }
    </script>

    <script src="http://localhost:8081/returnUser?username=johndoe@gmail.com&password=testpassword&callback=callbackFunc" type="text/javascript">

    </script>


</body>
```

I have tried this in IE8, Firefox12 and Chrome. When I run it through firefox i see that the url is returning the appropriate JSON:

[{"lastName":"Doe","password":"testpassword","userId":2,"firstName":"John","username":"johndoe@gmail.com"}]

Any help would be welcome.

Many thanks.

Comment: If your server supports jsonp it actually should have returned _callbackFunc({"lastName":"Doe","password":"testpassword","userId":2,"firstName":"John","username":"johndoe@gmail.com"})_

Answer (score 3):

The server should return the JavaScript

```
callbackFunc({"lastName":"Doe","password":"testpassword","userId":2,"firstName":"John","username":"johndoe@gmail.com"})
```

for this to work.